# Starting AsyncTask recursively after a gap of 5 minutes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to create an instance of a class (which extends `Asynctask`) and call its `execute()` method after every 5 minutes. For that I tried to call `Thread.sleep(5*60*1000))` in `onPostExecute()` method and then create a new instance of the class. The code is as below.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        //whatever I want to do
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Thread.sleep(5*60*1000);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute("my String");
    }
}
```

But using this code blocks the UI for 5 minutes. I read somewhere that the code in `onPostExecute()` is executed in the UI thread. This explains why the UI is blocked. 
But then how do I create a new instance of `AsyncTask` without blocking the UI ?

Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code in the onPostExecute.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MyAsyncTask().execute("my String");
        }
    }, 5*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
       new MyAsyncTask().execute("my String");
 }
}, 0, 5*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to repeat tasks, but after a lot of experimentation I have found that running a regular task without the activity actually running should be through a AlarmManager. All other techniques are for app's that need a UI running. Handler works well @Sagar's response is good.

Check out [example of alarm manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128091/setting-up-alarm-manager-is-creating-2-instances-of-my-main-activity/16134932#16134932), you want to run as a background / without UI.

Comment: Note, its a pain to get AlarmManager working, the link above is from production working code.