# How can I get an Android app to run continuously

Tags: android

If I start my app on one of my android devices (Nexus 10, or a Galaxy Note 2), lie the device down and stop touching it, before too long the operating system turns off the screen and pauses the app.  Is there any way that I can get the app to instruct the operating system to turn off the screen but keep the app running?

NB: This app won't ever be for public release, it's just for my own research.

Comment: Perhaps another different approach is to start a Service...

Comment: Check this out `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128091/setting-up-alarm-manager-is-creating-2-instances-of-my-main-activity/16134932#16134932`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wake lock from [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

[PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) seems to be what you want.

This will keep the CPU running even when the screen is off. Keep in mind that this will drain the battery significantly faster, and your app may still be paused or killed if the system needs resources, like during a phone call perhaps.

Comment: you can add a service that looks to see if the app is no longer running and restart it, in the event that Android cleans it up. Also... you should consider whether or not you need the app to actually be "running" or if a service portion can just do whatever background stuff you want happening in perpetuity without the Activity actually hanging around.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel ...How would the service check if the app is running if it is part of the app? Won't it get paused/killed with the app? Also, in this case the problem is that the device pauses practically all apps when it is in sleep mode. Wake locks are the only way to prevent that

Comment: I wasn't contradicting your wake_lock solution, I was adding to it.  You don't need your service to run all the time, you just need it to be spurred into action by an alarm. It can take a look to see if your app is alive (there are a lot of ways to see if the app is alive) and if not bring it to life.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Yes, that makes sense too.