# how to get Location object every 10 minutes in android

Tags: android, android-location

please someone give me a code can recover the GPS position or every n minutes, I tested several code but no result

Please someone give me a tutorial or a small program for that, I'm really stuck

```
public final class TrackListener implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    public boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public TrackListener(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Contexts.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Log.v("isGPSEnabled", "=" + isGPSEnabled);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Log.v("isNetworkEnabled", "=" + isNetworkEnabled);

            if (isGPSEnabled == false && isNetworkEnabled == false) {
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(TrackListener.this);
        }
    }
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                "ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS");
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(Contexts.getAppContext(), "GPS Disable ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(Contexts.getAppContext(), "GPS enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
```

but when calling "getLocation()" in the class activity I find a fatal problem

```
 04-28 08:41:55.126: W/dalvikvm(16004): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testss/com.example.testss.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at com.example.testss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    04-28 08:41:55.186: E/AndroidRuntime(16004):    ... 11 more
    04-28 08:46:55.255: I/Process(16004): Sending signal. PID: 16004 SIG: 9
```

Comment: do you have the permission to access the GPS?

Comment: yes i did                                                        <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission                  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >                       </uses-permission>

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` in `MainActivity` line 27. Nothing to do with the code you have posted. Initialize your objects correctly.

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger, it would be very useful in this case to determine where your error is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get Location object every n minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258156/how-to-get-location-object-every-n-minutes)

Comment: how to use  the debugger

Comment: yes it is my question, but I'm another parcque the other question is blocked

Comment: Why the downvote ? getting location thingy to work is a pain without help.

Comment: What line is line 27 ?

Comment: The idea behind your code is correct, LocationListener should callback when your location changes or time expires. But beware this does not work on Samsung phones. Nor do they respond to support requests at all. So no hope for getting help from Samsung to get this code working. You are better off calling `getLastKnownLocation`.

Comment: Have you tried the code below ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be answered in 2 parts.

- [calling a background service every 10 mins, using alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128091/setting-up-alarm-manager-is-creating-2-instances-of-my-main-activity/16134932#16134932)
- Using a LocationManager and LocationListener, choosing between (or both) network and gps provider. If chose network provider, since gps provider takes a hell a long time to connect and I dont need the accuracy of gps. Network provider is accurate upto 250ms (i got 1 bad sample in 5 hours). Keep in mind LocationListener, does not work on Samsung phones (since samsung phones have heavily customized build of Android, and they dont do a thorough job of porting).

OR

- I used a **force get my location now** kinda call `God.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)`

In addition to the alarm code above, put the following code in the onHandleIntent

```
@Override
final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mainContext = getApplicationContext() ;
    Location myLocation;
        if (God.locationManager == null)
            God.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocation = God.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (myLocation != null)
            onLocationChanged(myLocation);
        else {
            God.notifications.setSpeedNotification();
        }
}
```

Note : You can choose LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, just be ready to test it under open sky (no clouds) and about 5 mins to sync with 4-5 satellites.

Comment: Be ready to put in a lot of Log debug statements and debug like crazy on multiple phones. Location is not easy to get working smoothly. Will take time and effort.