# Android - Get the location every 30 minutes

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked many times but I can't find an answer that fit my problem.

I have an application which has to know the Location of the user every 30 minutes (in order to do specific stuff). **I do not want the application to check if the Location has changed**. I only need to get it every 30 minutes so **I don't want to use the onLocationChanged() method**.

I use the "passive" way and not the gps or network way so I don't need to "find" the best provider, I already know it.

Is there a way to it ?

Thanks a lot.

Julien

Comment: Search more, there is a lot of help on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872880/onreceiver-of-broadcastreceiver-not-called-alarmmanager  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261495/how-to-get-location-object-every-10-minutes-in-android/16263746#16263746

Comment: Indeed. I found one of them after my post. Apologies

Answer (score 2):

You could set up an alarm for every 30 minutes and check getLastKnownLocation.  However, the last known location is only actively updated if at least 1 app is registered for location updates-  so you'll still have to register yourself to make sure that variable is updated.

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter("broadcast reciever class name here") );
Intent i=new Intent("broadcast reciever class name here");
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30*60*1000, pi);
```

This will set an alarm for every 30 minutes.  If you want this to continue to go off after the activity is dead, set it in a Service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not sure I understand it well. Could you be more specific with an example ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination