# Why does my Alarm not get called?

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I am calling a Alarm every 30 seconds. It is not being called. What am I doing wrong.

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent
        .getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 30, pi);
```

My OnAlarmReceiver

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // PullPendingRequests.acquireStaticLock(context);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Taxeeta:PullPendingRequets", "CallService Location");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, DriverService.class));
}
}
```

My Manifest contents for Alarm and Service

```
 <service
        android:name="com.taxeeta.DriverService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.taxeeta.support.OnAlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: IS OnAlarmReceiver class inner class of some activity?

Comment: No, it is not. Its a external independent class.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the code to, [thanks to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128091/setting-up-alarm-manager-is-creating-2-instances-of-my-main-activity/16134932#16134932)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notifyintent = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    notifyintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notifyintent.setAction("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");
    PendingIntent notifysender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notifyintent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 20 * 1000,
            notifysender);
```